# How to check< 2 and > 4 checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

I am trying to check the user input for `greater than 2` and `less than 4` checkbox selected.

I have to do this check before the form gets submitted.

Although I am using AlloyUI for client side validation. You can help me with vanilla javascript.

Please help me with my code...

```
<% for(loop here which generates more than one checkbox) { %>
<form name=".." method=".." action=".." onSubmit="return checkBox();">
  <input type="checkbox" id=".." name=".."/>
</form>
%>
```

My javascript

```
function checkBox(){
        alert("start");
        var total = 0;
        var max = form.checkcompare.length;
        alert(max);
        for(var idx = 0; idx < max; idx++)
        {
        if(eval("document.compareform.checkcompare[" + idx + "].checked") == true)
        {
            alert("checking");
        total += 1;
        }
        }
        if (total==2 || total==4)
        {
        /*  document.compareform.submit(); */
        alert("success");
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Select minimum of 2 or maximum of 4 Estimates');
        }
        //alert("You selected " + total + " boxes.");
        }
```

Its not working..can someone help..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function getNumberOfCheckedCheckboxes ( form ) {
  var returnValue = 0;
  var inputElements = form.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i ++) {
    if (inputElements.type == "checkbox") {
      if (inputElments.checked) {
        returnValue ++;
      }
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something tells me you have little idea what you're doing.

First off, you're creating one form for EVERY checkbox. Open the form tag, then put in your loop to add the checkboxes, then close the form.

Now for your script...

`form` is undefined, so you can get its elements. `form.checkcompare` is undefined, so you can't get its length. You probably want to pass `this` in the `onSubmit` event (`onSubmit="return checkBox(this);"`), and `function checkBox(form)`. Then use `form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');`.

Next, why in the world are you using evil `eval` just to get an array index?

As if that weren't enough you say you want "between 2 and 4" but your code considers "3" invalid.

Finally, you're not `return`ing anything.

Fixed (and improved) code:

```
function checkBox(form){ 
    var total = 0; 
    var boxes = form.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    if (boxes < 2 || boxes > 4)
        return true;
    else { 
        alert('Select minimum of 2 or maximum of 4 Estimates'); 
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have it right in my code. Form and then the loop within.
And I tried your code and the form gets submitted without any alert as well. Can you do me a favour..send me the entire html if you may. As I have to alter to AUI...this should help me gr8 deal.